# formatting table cell content in django-tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

Love django-tables... but something that I'm sure is trivial to solve is giving me fits.  When the value I pass for a given row/column is like:

```
some<br/>random<br/>words<br/>returned
```

I want the browser to parse and render the content in that cell... to look like this:

some
random
words
returned

*not* escape the content I'm passing and display it like this:

```
some<br/>random<br/>words<br/>returned
```

Surely there's some flag or option that I've missed?

Comment: Can you show me your `Table` code, and how you're supplying the HTML value to the table?

Comment: For the sake of clarity, let's say all columns for the table are simply column_name = tables.Column() and that I'm messy enough to have the stored procedure output that's bound to the table supplying string values which include the markup.  I was actually doing it a little differently, but I'm not sure that it matters in the context of this conversation.

Answer (score 7):

Use mark_safe as follows:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class testTable(tables.Tables):
    id = tables.Column()
    html = tables.Column()

    def render_html(self):
        return mark_safe('some<br/>random<br/>words<br/>returned')
```

Same question was asked [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237235/how-to-disable-html-encoding-when-using-context-in-django)

Comment: to return the variable rather than a static string, one needs to pass the value parameter, as in render_html(self, value) and return mark_safe(value + ' <b>more stuff</b>'). Took me a while to figure this out ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If some of your data already contains HTML, the simplest solution is to use a `TemplateColumn` rather than a normal column and mark the value as safe:

```
class Table(tables.Table):
    html_data = tables.TemplateColumn("{{ value|safe }}")
    # ...
```

Comment: very useful if the data is not defined as a property. Regneel's solution only works if the data is defined as a property in the django model.

Answer (score 1):

HA.  Found it.  It wasn't django-tables2 that was auto-escaping my content, it was the django templating system itself: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AutoEscaping.

I had to change my template code to render the django-table2 like this:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
    {% render_table route_table %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: I actually agree.  It's a hack.  I'm pretty sure there's some way to use a template to format individual cell contents, but I couldn't for the life of me get the bound data passed through when I tried it that way.

Comment: I guess my "answer" should have made it clear that by "found it" I meant I'd figured out the cause for the behavior and a way to prevent it.  A real "answer" would do something other than disabling autoescape... which is the default behavior for a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render as html your column value

```py
import django_tables2 as tables
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class testTable(tables.Tables):
    # column 1
    html = tables.Column()
    # ....
  
    def render_html(self, value):
        return mark_safe(value)
```