# How is data in a column changed in django-tables2?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am trying to find a way to modify the data displayed in django-tables2. In my data I have two columns "DOI Number" and "link". I am trying to edit the "DOI Number" column so that it will display as

```
< a href="link">DOI Number< /a>
```

so that the data within the "DOI Number" column will be a hyperlink.

The django-tables2 documentation shows this code to change the data within a column. What exactly is this code doing? I cannot figure out how it is supposed to be used to modify the data.

```
from django_tables2 import A
data = {"abc": {"one": {"two": "three"}}}
A("abc.one.two").resolve(data)
```

django-tables2 documentation section http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#specifying-alternative-data-for-a-column

Comment: possible duplicate of [formatting table cell content in django-tables2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378717/formatting-table-cell-content-in-django-tables2)

Answer (score 0):

By defining new columns the data that is displayed can be changed.

```
class tmntable(tables.Table):
    new_column_name = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href="{{model_name.url_id}}">{{model_name.text_to_display}}</a>')

    class Meta:
        model = model_name
        fields = ('column_name', 'other_column_name', 'third_column_name', 'Reference DOI')
```

Fields lists all of the columns to display within the table. Other table types are URLColumn and LinkColumn and more information can be found here http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#django_tables2.columns.BooleanColumn